# move folder to another one microsoft API getting this error: ErrorItemNotFound

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I created an app with permissions:

- Mail.ReadWrite
- offline_access
- User.Read

[image]

So then I get the permissions from the user and get the final token.
I'm able to get the emails with `GET /me/messages/`
I'm able to get the folders names and ids with with `GET /me/mailFolders/`
But 'm not able to move the email to another folder,
I'm doing this:

```
POST /me/messages/{msg id}/move
Content-type: application/json

{
  "destinationId": "junkemail"
}
```

I tried to send it to other folders, even with folders created manually,I've used the folder name, folder id, but still doesn't work, I always get the same error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also having `Mail.ReadWrite, offline_access,  User.Read` permissions. In order to move email, I did the following steps-

- Fetched the message Id from below-

[image]

- Invoked `POST /me/messages/{id}/move` using above Id and email moved successfully to `Junk Email` folder.

[image]

**Please note**, Id will get changed once the email is moved to any other folder.

- If you will make `GET /me/messages/{id}` now using the Id generated in first step then you will get below error-

[image]

So, I would suggest you to make `GET /me/messages/{id}` call to check whether the email Id is exist before making `POST /me/messages/{id}/move` call.

Comment: thanks, I actually did what you suggest but didn't work, I'm trying to do it now and it works, so probably I need some rest or it as a temporal bug?
Anyway, thank you very much for your time